# JQuery click operation only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#button_title_delete").click(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({type:'POST', 
            url:'delete.php',
            data: 'id='+$("bid").val(), 
            success: function(veri) { $("#delete_result").html(veri);}
        });
    });
```

When i click the button with "button_title_delete" id, this function works for only one time. What am i doing wrong? How should i fix this problem?

Comment: does the new page 'delete.php' contain the same button with the same code/logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because you're replacing the button on the `success` callback of your AJAX function. You need to use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to attach the click event.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that I'm replacing the button in some other JQuery request. Thanks for pointing that out, much appreciated.

Comment: Note: you need to use `.on` in "delegate mode" by passing a selector as the 2nd parameter.

Comment: @Colin: No problem.  jQuery uses `.on` for all your event binding needs, so I just wanted to make sure you used it the way you need.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the button is inside of `$("#delete_result")`.  When you do `$("#delete_result").html(veri)`, you are removing the button (and its event), and then making a new button.

You need to make the button have a "live" event.  Like so:

```
$("#delete_result").on("click", "#button_title_delete", function(){
    jQuery.ajax({type:'POST', 
            url:'delete.php',
            data: 'id='+$("bid").val(), 
            success: function(veri) { $("#delete_result").html(veri);}
        });
    });
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pujr8/